# How many combinations can be generated with this set?

Tags: combinations, factorial

I have a certain set that has 4 values of set in total and I am trying to get the total number of combinations that are possible with this set.
The set is:
`({1-5},{1-5},{A-Z},{0-999})`

So an example of the set would be:
`(2, 4, P, 121)`

Now the set follows the order as given, but the each value is randomly assigned such that another example would be `(3, 1, Z, 345)`

The way I am calculating this is by using factorial such as:
`(5 * 5 * 26 * 1000) * 4!`

So is this the right way to calculate?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: Let $A,B,C,$ respectively denote $\{1,2,\cdots,5\}$,  $\{A,B,\cdots,Z\}$,  $\{1,2,\cdots,999\}$. To clarify, do you wish to count the number of sets of the type $\{a_1,a_2,b,c\}$ where $a_i\in A,b\in B,c\in C$?

Comment: @Shahab Yes and from my set, as you see how I am calculating. Is this right? Also the end set starts from ```0,1,2,...999```

Comment: You shouldn't multiply by $4!$. Consider a simpler example:$A=\{1,2\},B=\{x,y,z\}$. The requisite sets of the form $\{a,b\}$ with $a\in A,b\in B$ are $2\cdot 3$ in number, namely $\{1,x\}$, $\{1,y\}$, $\{1,z\}$, $\{2,x\}$, $\{2,y\}$, $\{2,z\}$.